# Looping through a dataset in R and count occurences of variables

Tags: r, loops

I found an interesting data-set from a psychology study (data-set is called WearingTShirt), and I would like to replicate the results. I would need to summarize two variables into a single variable. This is what I have written:

## Create empty variable

PinkAndRed = 0

## Count instances of people wearing both pink and red and add 1

for i in WearingTShirt:
  PinkAndRed+1 if:
     WearingTShirt$PINKSHIRT==1 OR WearingTShirt$REDSHIRT==1

## Add variable to dataset

WearingTShirt$PinkAndRed

I have not much R experience (I wrote mostly in Python).

Comment: I think you need to read up some of the basics in r. None of your code will work except `PinkAndRed = 0`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is more in python than in R. The equivalent code in R for what you want to do is:

```
PinkAndRed = rep(0,dim(WearingTShirt)[1])

for(i in 1:dim(WearingTShirt)[1]){
    if((WearingTShirt$PINKSHIRT[i]==1) || (WearingTShirt$REDSHIRT[i]==1))
    {
    PinkAndRed[i] = 1
    }
}

WearingTShirt=cbind(WearingTShirt,PinkAndRed)
```

You need to review basics on R. There are countless small difference between R and python, such as parenthesis in loops or conditions, set the length of a loop (in the above code with dim you calculate the dimension of the dataset and by doing [1] you indicate that you want the number of rows)...

#### Update:

thanks to the comments i've realized that is not clear if you want a cumulative sum of the individuals with pink and red shirts or a variable which is 1 with the shirt is pink or red, and 0 in other case.

The code above is for a varaible that includes pink and red shirts in one variable.

If you want the sum you must use cumsum function as it's said in the comments

Comment: While this code possibly works, it's really not how you'd typically do this in R. Instead of a for loop it looks like a simple `cumsum` would do this faster, simpler and more readable. It also looks like you're never referencing the index `i` in your code

Comment: I've done this way for "translante" the code from python to R. And thanks for the `i` I forgot

Answer (score 0):

I would not choose to loop, but:

```
WearingTShirt$PinkAndRed <- ifelse(WearingTShirt$PINKSHIRT==1 | 
WearingTShirt$REDSHIRT==1,1,0)
```

PinkAndRed sounds more like PinkOrRed based on example given.